# Join two word in a item from a list python

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
['Fantasy', 'Young Adult', 'Paranormal', 'Paranormal Romance']
```

Is it possible to join the two words in an item like `'Young.Adult'`

I mean in general, not for that two words(the list only contains max two words).

Comment: You want to replace the space with `.`?

Comment: `'Young Adult'.replace(' ', '.')` and that for every item in the list.

Comment: i meant in general, just not for that words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it:

```py
for word in ['Fantasy', 'Young Adult', 'Paranormal', 'Paranormal Romance']:
    print(word.replace(" ", "."))
```

Comment: I am learning Python, thank you for pointing me to the right path.

Comment: I meant to update the list itself, but this answer give me an idea to use in another way.